# ENOENT, open '/app/public/index.html' nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm using heroku to host a nodejs app. I push a folder name `test` with the file tree like this:

```
-test
    /-server.js
    /-Procfile
    /-package.json
    /-public
        /-index.html
        /-style.css
        /script.js
```

I the server.js file I handle the request like this:

```
fa.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.end(error);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
        res.end(data);
    }
});
```

And when I test the thing, it came up with this:
`ENOENT, open '/app/public/index.html'`
i dont know why it refer to the `/app` folder.
I tested it locally, it return the pure html page with no css and js.

Comment: Hey man, did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same exact issue right now.  No idea why it's looking in /app/ directory?!

Comment: take a look at the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the project structure down one level.

You should be pushing the contents of the `test` directory as your application, not a repo with the `test` directory that is the application.

```
-server.js
-Procfile
-package.json
-public
  /-index.html
  /-style.css
  /script.js
```

Comment: that is exactly what i did. I use `cd` to go to my app and then `git push heroku master`